# WebHostBuilder.run / host.Run() is throwing "Server Error"

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm trying to run/debug .Net core webapi applicataion and I see WebHostBuilder.Run() call is failing with "Server Error". , Code is not entering catch block though some exception is thrown in host.Run() call.
[image]
Once I enable exception setting to catch all error, I'm getting "SocketException" during host.Run() call.

Any idea/suggestion to identify the root cause?

[image]

Comment: Maybe a firewall is blocking the connection?

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Thanks @RobertPaulsen and svick for your suggestions.  I've managed to find the root cause(missing dll/config sections) by adding   app.UseUnhandledExceptionLogger(); and app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); in startup.  After adding, I could see meaningful error messages.